# React Show data with page refresh on Button click

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, show-hide

I have array of object as data. The data is displayed on initial page load. When Clear Book button is called with clearBooks() function, I set array to empty (No Data is displayed) and change button value to `Show Books`

What I am trying to achieve is when `Show Books` button is clicked I would like to show all objects as before. I though of refreshing page with `window.location.reload();` when `Show Books` is clicked (If there are better solution, open to use them). I need help to achieve this functionality in code

main.js

```
const clearBooks = () => {
    if (buttonTitle === "Clear Books") {
      setButtonTitle("Show Books");
    }
    setBooksData([]);
  };
return (
    <section className="booklist">
      {booksData.map((book, index) => {
        return (
          <Book key={index} {...book}>
          </Book>
        );
      })}
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={clearBooks}>
          {buttonTitle}
        </button>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
```

Data

```
export const books = [
  {
    id: 1,
    img: "https://m.media/_QL65_.jpg",
    author: " A ",
    title: "B",
    
  },
{
    id: 2,
    img: "https://m.media/_QL65_.jpg",
    author: " A ",
    title: "B",
    
  },
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could store the originally fetched data into a separate state and reset the `booksData` array by setting its value equal to that state on the `Show Books` click:

```
const [originalBooksData, setOriginalBooksData] = useState([]);
const [booksData, setBooksData] = useState([]);

const fetchBooks = async () => {
    ...
    // After booksData have been fetched set originalBooksData equal to it
    setOriginalBooksData(booksData)
}

const clearBooks = () => {
  if (buttonTitle === 'Clear Books') {
    // Clear the books
    setButtonTitle('Show Books');
    setBooksData([]);
  } else {
    // Reset the books
    setBooksData(originalBooksData);
  }
};

...
```

Of course, you will need to set the `originalBooksData` equal to `booksData` when the data are loaded.
This will prevent the need to refresh the page when clearing the data.

Comment: this seems to overdoing although it working, as book data is handling the book state so when again resetting to initially, it should load the initial set again in the same object. using multiple states for the same is not recommended way

Comment: @AnshukSharma Feel free to propose a better solution, I'm just here to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `useState` hook.

```
const books = [
  {
    id: 1,
    img: "https://m.media/_QL65_.jpg",
    author: "A",
    title: "B",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    img: "https://m.media/_QL65_.jpg",
    author: " A ",
    title: "B",
  },
]

const [bookList, setBookList] = useState(books);

const clearBooks = () => {
  setBookList([]);
}

const showBooks = () => {
  setBookList(books);
}
```

Set bookList to empty when you need to clear book list and to `books` object when yoou want to show your list books.

Comment: setBookList(""); should be set to empty [] then string, should not change the type